# ES7 double colon binding syntax parsing error

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I've tried out the double colon operator on babel's website
https://babeljs.io/repl
But when I try to use babel-core and babel-loader to parse the same in my code, the following error shows up.

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/dev/housing-litmus/client/components/StepBuilder.jsx: Unexpected token (30:46)
  28 |              {
  29 |                  steps.map(function(step){
> 30 |                  return <StepField id={step._id} addStep={::self.addStep} removeStep={self.removeStep.bind(self)} commands={commands}/>
     |          



at Parser.pp.raise (/home/dev/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/dev/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:82:8)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/home/dev/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:425:12)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (/home/dev/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:412:22)
```

I've tried updating babel to the latest npm version available.

Answer (score 6):

Notice in that repl link that it doesn't work unless you tick "experimental". You have to turn on the [experimental flag](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/) (stage 0). You can do this in the CLI as the link shows, or in a `.babelrc`, or if you are using something like webpack you can add this to the loader config under a `query` object.